# How to create a shell script to create a folder by using the today's date to take backup using rsync command on every evening around 7 pm

Tags: command-line, scripts

1] I want to create a script which matches the today's date >> with server's date format.

2] If it matches then, it will create the folder named "$date" itself in the mentioned path "/tmp/test/files/testing/".

3] Moreover, it will search for the files which are created by today's date with the help of "find" command from "/var/www/path" and take the back up with the help of the rsync command of those files into /mnt/ folder.

I'm kinda new shell scripter however, kindly help me with the script.

**________________________________________________________________________________**

What I've did until now is :>>>>>>>

```
##!/bin/bash 
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")


mkdir /tmp/test/files/testing/"date +%b%Y%m%d"/$now &&


find . -type f -newermt 2019-06-10 -ls -exec rsync -avzh {} /mnt/Data/exes/10-June-2019/ \;  &&

mysqldump -h localhost -u username -ppassword production > /mnt/Data/date +%b%Y%m%d/productionDate.sql
```

**________________________________________________________________________________**

Thanks,
Bakula

Comment: What do you have so far? Which part of this is giving you trouble? Please [edit] your question and show us what you have written so we don't tell you things you already know.

Comment: I'm bit confused that if this script would work but, I've tried to create as per what I've asked for. : 

[


#!/bin/bash now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

mkdir /tmp/test/files/testing/"date +%b%Y%m%d"/$now &&

mysqldump -h localhost -u username -ppassword production > /mnt/Data/date +%b%Y%m%d/productionDate.sql &&

find . -type f -newermt 2019-06-10 -ls -exec rsync -avzh {} /mnt/Data/exes/10-June-2019/ \;                                                                                  
 ]

Comment: I wanted to create this script just because, I would be running it every day at evening around 7 pm. Could you please guide me with steps?

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question and show us what you have. as you can see, it's impossible to read in the comments.

Comment: Okay, as you mentioned, I've updated my question with the work I've did until now on it. Kindly help me. Thanks.